# WSGI Application not found on OpenShift

Tags: python, django, openshift

I started from the Django template application in OpenShift, pushed it to OpenShift, and it ran without issue. After making a couple minor changes to settings.py and /.openshift/action_hooks/deploy, the application no longer runs (404 not found). In the command window, during deployment, I see `CLIENT_ERROR: WSGI application not found`. The build/deploy succeeds and finishes deployment.

As stated before, the home page now returns a 404. The logs indicate that application.py is not found. If I SSH into the deployment folder, I can find the file exactly where it is reported missing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What changes did you make? If you changed the entry point you need to update your `OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION` environment variable as per this release article: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/openshift-online-march-2014-release-blog

Comment: The changes I made to settings.py were generally to hook up postgres. The deploy changes basically just run manage.py. I don't think the environment variable has anything to do with this, as the logs indicate that Apache is looking for wsgi/application, and application.py exists there.